# Why is the ListViewBuilder showing duplicate values?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote the following simple application to query my database. I'm trying to use a listviewbuilder to show each of the show names on a different card. I know I have two shows in the database and so I should have two cards (Game of Thrones and Super Bowl). So why is this showing 4 cards (screenshot below)? Thanks for the help!

[image]

```
// This is the model class
class Mod {
  final String name;
  final String nextEpisode;
  final String prevEpisode;

  Mod(this.name, this.nextEpisode, this.prevEpisode);

  Mod.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        nextEpisode = json['nextEpisode'],
        prevEpisode = json['prevEpisode'];
}

// This is the screen class
class FTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FTest2State createState() => _FTest2State();
}

class _FTest2State extends State<FTest2> {
  List<Mod> list = List();
  final showNameList = List();

  Future MakeCall() {
    final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('shows');
    mainReference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value;
//      print(values.toString());
      values.forEach((key, value) {
        showNameList.add(value['name']);
      });
      print(showNameList);
    });
  }

/*  MakeCall() {
    final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('shows');
    mainReference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value;
      print(values.toString());
      values.forEach((key, value) {
//        print(key);
        print(value['name']);
      });
    });
  }*/

  void getData() {
    MakeCall();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('This is App Bar for the FB Test'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.pages, color: Colors.white),
            label: Text('Query', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: () {
              getData();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: MakeCall(),
              builder: (context, mainReference) {
/*                if (mainReference.hasData == null) {
                  return Container();
                }*/
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: showNameList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(showNameList[index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below

Step 1: To avoid `FutureBuilder` rebuilds unnecessarily https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11426#issuecomment-416170661

```
Future _future;

@override
  void initState() {
    _future = MakeCall();
    super.initState();
  }

FutureBuilder(
              future: _future,
              builder: (context, mainReference) {
```

Step 2: If `MakeCall()` should always return same data 
You need to call `showNameList.clear();` in `MakeCall()` to avoid add duplicate value 
I can not simulate this case, it's base on your data

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Mod {
  final String name;
  final String nextEpisode;
  final String prevEpisode;

  Mod(this.name, this.nextEpisode, this.prevEpisode);

  Mod.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        nextEpisode = json['nextEpisode'],
        prevEpisode = json['prevEpisode'];
}

// This is the screen class
class FTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FTest2State createState() => _FTest2State();
}

class _FTest2State extends State<FTest2> {
  List<Mod> list = List();
  final showNameList = List();
  Future _future;

  Future MakeCall() {
    print("Make Call");
    /*final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('shows');
    mainReference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value;
//      print(values.toString());
      values.forEach((key, value) {
        showNameList.add(value['name']);
      });
      print(showNameList);
    });*/
    showNameList.clear();
    showNameList.add({"name":"super"});
    showNameList.add({"name":"game"});
    print(showNameList.length);
  }

/*  MakeCall() {
    final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('shows');
    mainReference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value;
      print(values.toString());
      values.forEach((key, value) {
//        print(key);
        print(value['name']);
      });
    });
  }*/

  void getData() {
    MakeCall();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = MakeCall();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('This is App Bar for the FB Test'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.pages, color: Colors.white),
            label: Text('Query', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: () {
              getData();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: _future,
              builder: (context, mainReference) {
/*                if (mainReference.hasData == null) {
                  return Container();
                }*/
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: showNameList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(showNameList[index]["name"]),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,       
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: FTest2(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear showNameList before re-instantiating it with new future values else it will add onto the last stored values and your list will keep growing with duplicates